# How to add fullscreen loader only when refreshing page and page fade page transitions in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I want to add a fullscreen loader to my Next.JS app to appear only when refreshing a page or loading it for a first time. It should not appear when routing between different pages. Also, I'd like to add `fade` transition when navigating between pages, like here https://www.vidstack.io/. How can I do that in Next.JS? Here is the example of the fullscreen loading I'd like to implement (https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vj4saw?file=app%2Flayout.tsx). Maybe it's possible to do with `framer-motion`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do transition effects by using the `framer-motion` library for React. Here is a simple example:

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

export default function PageTransition({ children }) {
  return (
    <motion.main
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ duration: 1 }} // Adjust the duration as needed
    >
      {children}
    </motion.main>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
"use client"
import PageTransition from "@/components/PageTransition";
import React from 'react'

export default function SimplePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <PageTransition>
        <main className="text-center uppercase">
          <p>
            Text.
          </p>
        </main>
      </PageTransition>
    </>
  )
}
```